# Submit form after Stripe Token successfully created

Tags: php, jquery, forms, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Checkout, and want to submit a form with details from the end user after a token has been created by Stripe.

The issue I'm having is only the details from stripe are being submitted, I'm not too advanced with jQuery so this has been difficult - I would appriciate some help!

Here is the HTML for the forms:

Stripe:

```
<form action="charge.php" method="post">
                            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
                            class="stripe-button"
                            data-key="'.$stripe['publishable_key'].'"
                            data-amount="300"
                            data-name=""
                            data-description="Plan 2 (£3 per month)"
                            data-panel-label="Subscribe"
                            data-label="Subscribe"
                            data-locale="auto">
                            data-allow-remember-me="false">
                            data-currency="gbp"
                            </script>
                            </form>
```

My form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="includes/add-function.php" method="POST" >


                            <div class="contact-form">              

                            <input type="text" name="business-name" id="title" placeholder="Business Name" />
                            <input type="text" name="business-desc" id="description" placeholder="Business Description" />      
                            <input type="text" name="website" id="url" placeholder="Website" />
                            <input type="text" name="contact-email" id="logpassword" placeholder="Contact Email" />
                            <input type="text" name="contact-phone" id="category" placeholder="Category" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2048000" />
                            <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="image">

                            </div>


                            <div class="comment-form">

                            <input id="line1" name="line1" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 1" /> 
                            <input id="line2" name="line2" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
                            <input id="town" name="city" type="text" placeholder="Town" />                      
                            <input id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Postcode" />      
                            </form>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What are the fields and `action`s of both forms? I've seen most payment gateways perform this by redirecting to an auto-submitted form - whether this can be done asynchronously, I'm not sure. However, I wonder why submitting the first form is being interrupted.

Comment: Updated my answer, both forms action is their corresponding script, however I have some jQuery which is meant to async submit both forms - however doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: `Therefore a user will either pay without recieving the service, or get the service for free` - I'm not sure what you mean with this. To verify a payment you should use Stripe's [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

Comment: I mean, without both of the forms submitting correctly, a user will either pay without recieving the service, or get the service for free. This isn't what I want

Comment: So what if I spoof the 2nd form then?

Comment: And achieve what exactly?

Comment: your code is intent very badly, and there is some thing wrong, `data-locale="auto">   data-allow-remember-me="false>  data-currency="gbp"` you close the code twice wrong place `>` you should close it once at the and like `data-currency="gbp">` and delete the extra `>`, please verify.

Comment: Thanks for the spot! Didn't realse that, I copy and pasted from Stripes website, then added extra parameters. The HTML Section is fine, I'm having issues with the javascript, here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4t5kosyw/) with the updated code. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @PublicDisplayName and receive the service w/out paying?

Comment: @DarkBee not 100% sure about spoofing a form using Stripes verification, as it needs to be a valid card in order for Stripe to charge it. This is why I want to 1. Submit to Stripe > 2. Successful Payment > 3. Submit to database

Comment: Just move the <script> from the first form to the second form, and then in includes/add-function.php charge the customer before you add it to the database.